# Cuando inicio Windows con Virtualbox me pide volver a instalarlo

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox

Ayer instalé windows con [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) en mi Mac, y andaba perfecto, pero hoy vuelvo a intentar abrirlo y me pide nuevamente que lo instale, es decir que coloque el código de compra de la imagen iso y todos los demás pasos. ¿Saben cuál puede ser mi problema?

Answer (score 2):

Es muy probable que en el orden de arranque de los discos tengas primero el disco óptico y cada vez que arranca la máquina virtual vuelva a cargar el cd de instalación.

Selecciona la máquina virtual en la que instalaste windows, dale a **configuración** y busca en la pestaña **Sistema** el **orden de arranque** ahí sube el disco duro a la primera posición ;-)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configuración > Sistema > Placa Base > Orden de Arranque.

Comment: Tambien deberias de quitar la imagen ISO porque puede que por eso cuando inicias arranca otra vez la instalación.